# Error while trying to Build APK, fails when profile option is enabled

Tags: unity, java, android-studio, build-process, profiler

When I build normally my android app it execute without no problems, but when I go to File -> Buil and Run and I eneble Development Build and Autoconnect to profiler I got this error

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/OpenJDK/Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.Camera2Wrapper found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleARCoreApi found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrApi found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy$4 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrVideo found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrVideo$GoogleVrVideoCallbacks found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$10 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$11 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$12 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$13 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$14 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$15 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$16 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$17 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$18 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$19 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$20 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$21 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$22 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$23 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$4 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$5 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$6 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$7 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$8 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$9 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$d found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$f found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityWebRequest found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityWebRequest$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityWebRequest$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$4 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$5 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.b found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.b$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.b$b found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.c found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.c$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.d found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.e found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.f found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.g found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.h found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.i found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.j found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.l found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.l$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.l$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.m found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.n found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.o found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.o$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.p found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.p$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.p$b found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$1$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$1$1$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$4 found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
   Duplicate class org.fmod.a found in modules classes-2.jar (:openix-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)

   Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 21s
 ]
 stdout[
      > Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
      > Task :preDebugBuild
      > Task :compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
      > Task :compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
      > Task :checkDebugManifest
      > Task :generateDebugBuildConfig
      > Task :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
      > Task :generateDebugSources
      > Task :javaPreCompileDebug
      > Task :mainApkListPersistenceDebug
      > Task :generateDebugResValues
      > Task :generateDebugResources
      > Task :mergeDebugResources
      > Task :createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
      > Task :processDebugManifest
      > Task :processDebugResources
      > Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
      > Task :compileDebugSources
      > Task :mergeDebugShaders
      > Task :compileDebugShaders
      > Task :generateDebugAssets
      > Task :mergeDebugAssets
      > Task :validateSigningDebug
      > Task :signingConfigWriterDebug
      > Task :checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

      Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
      Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
      See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings 18 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 1 up-to-date
                ]
      exit code: 1
      UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
      UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
      vUnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
      UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
      UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (Unit<message truncated>`
```

I'm using Unity 2018.4.4.f1 and in my project I have an *.aar file that I made using Android Studio

I would appreciate any help you can give

Answer (score 1):

You are using a plugin, either a `.aar` or `.jar`, that is compiled with the `UnityPlayer.jar` (or `classes.jar`) file. Both `classes.jar` are compiled in your final build, so it throws a duplicate class exception.

To avoid this, try to add on your plugin module gradle, on the dependencies config, the following:

```
compileOnly files('./libs/classes.jar') // Avoid redundant Unity Player in final application APK
```

So your `.gradle` looks like:

```
//...
dependencies {
    //...

    compileOnly files('./libs/classes.jar') // Avoid redundant Unity Player in final application APK
    ///...
}
//...
```